# Getting Value from Nested Array -- PHP Wordpress --

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `get_post_meta` like below:

```
$job_owner = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assignedUsers', true);
```

That returns the following:

```
(
    [total] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 440968
                    [firstName] => John
                    [lastName] => Doe
                    [email] => john@website.com
                )

        )

)
```

I am trying to grab the values from the object but catch an error each time I simply try and use `echo $job_owner`. Error is - **Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**

I have tried to use:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($job_owner), true);
```

Which returns the arrays:

```
Array
(
    [total] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 440968
                    [firstName] => Megan
                    [lastName] => Collins
                    [email] => megan@bridgeviewit.com
                )

        )

)
```

But I cannot seem to get anything to return using `echo $array[0]->id` etc...

My ideal scenario is to use the array values as variables to use throughout the theme.

Comment: It's clear that you have to go down the chain of keys, first comes `data`, so we have `$job_owner['data']`, then we have an entry at index `0`, so we got `$job_owner['data'][0]` and now we're at the `stdClass Object`, where you can access any property it owns, like id: `$job_owner['data'][0]->id`.

Comment: @dbf thanks for this. I ran down the chain, but was using [data] and getting the unnamed variable error. Making it a string allowed me to go down the line. 

I wasn't getting a return using `$job_owner['data'][0]->id` but bracketing the array keys did the trick $job_owner['data'][0]['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

So with echo `$array[0]->id` are trying to get the 0th element of that array which is total. So  `echo $array[0]->id` should fail but  `echo $array[0]` should return 1. If you change your request to `$array[data][0]->id` or `$array[1][0]->id` that should get you the value you are looking for - the id of the first element in the data bit.

$array[data][0]->id

Comment: Try to explain your answer a bit what the problem might be.